# Image map resizer doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to use image map resizer on my website but there is something wrong. I'm maping image in my header. I'm using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://davidjbradshaw.com/imagemap-resizer/js/imageMapResizer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('map').imageMapResize();
    });
</script>
```

And my map:

```
<img src="link_to_image" usemap="#map" width="100%" />
<map name="map">
    <area target="" alt="" title="" href="http://nowa.cwr-poznan.pl/" coords="124,152,109" shape="circle">
</map>
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Please provide more information about what isn't working. Do you get an errors in your browser console?

Comment: I want to map only logo from my header - not whole image (logo and picture). When whole image is displayed (width 1500px) everything is good, but in lower resolutions mapped circle doesn't fit to logo as in original resolution

Comment: @Andrej229 he is getting the good ole: $ is not defined error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of scripts on there. Try to avoid a potential conflict by changing your on ready to this format and see if that was the issue:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('map').imageMapResize();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for advice and help! Your code fixed my problem. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Just as a side note, things like jquery and other libs that are typically used on ready should be loaded just above the END body along with any custom scripts you have related to your app in order of dependencies. I can see with that site it may be a pretty big task to undertake.